# Clarification on a .reduce() method in my code

Tags: javascript

```
 const els = {
    scoreInEl: null, //number <input>
    maxInEl: null, //number <input>
    percentInEl: null, //number <input>
    percentEl: null, //Output
    gradeEl: null, //Output
    scoreUp: null, //Output
    scoreDown: null, //Output
    percentOut: null //Output
  };
    
  Object.keys(els).reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = document.querySelector("#" + k), o), els); //point of interest
```

So I have this code here that deals with the `.reduce()` method and I would like further information about my specific case.

I understand the the Object.keys takes each and every name of the element, such as `scoreUp`

So if you look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) documentation on this it says that you take the last element and the first element and that would be `o` and `k`.

Does the `o[k]` make the `scoreUp: null;` equal something, and what does it make it equal.

I don't think I understand anything in the query selector, or what the any of the `o` or `k` mean in: `document.querySelector("#" + k), o,), els)` but I do understand that the `#` means a css id and that the `els` is the object itself, and in this case would be the initial value.

Doing a `console.log(Object.keys...)` returns a bunch of confusing information, but from what I can tell its similar to doing something like `console.log(document.getElementById()`

What I really want from this is an answer to my questions, or a better source than the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to explain it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through what you're saying step-by-step first and see whether it's true or false.

> I understand the the Object.keys takes each and every name of the element, such as `scoreUp`

Yes, `Object.keys` returns an array of the keys of an object.

> So if you look at MDN documentation on this it says that you take the last element and the first element and that would be `o` and `k.

No, that's false. In reduce, the callback function's first two arguments are the accumulator (the output object, or what everything in the array is reduced into), and the current item in the array.

> Does the `o[k]` make the `scoreUp: null;` equal something, and what does it make it equal.

The `o[k]` accesses the key/value pair in the object `o` with the key being the value of `k`. It doesn't 'make `scoreUp: null;` equal something', it just is standard property access notation.

You don't need to use `reduce` here - it's only necessary when you want to manipulate (usually group) items of an array. This is modifying each key/value pair in an object. For that, I would recommend either a loop over `Object.keys` (note looping, not using `reduce`):

```js
Object.keys(els).forEach(k => els[k] = document.querySelector("#" + k));
```

Or a for-in loop which will effectively do the same thing.

```js
for (const k in els) {
    els[k] = document.querySelector("#" + k);
}
```

Comment: What would be a really good use for the .reduce method?

Comment: This might help you understand the `Array.reduce()` method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: A really good use could be, say, to reduce an array of objects with values attached to them and collect all of the 'like' objects in an array. Here's a demo, with logic you see a fair bit (summing values within an array of object): https://jsfiddle.net/JBDouble05/pga61b74/

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent Any time you need to "reduce" a collection to a single output value; as stated in the answer, grouping is one such thing, but there are others.

Comment: @Steve yes, I have that link included in my question, I didn't understand it

Comment: @JackBashford That is a wonderful example, and I can see uses for the .reduce method now, that is really cool, but I will now be implementing the .forEach, which I also need a bit more practice with too lol.

Answer (score 2):

> So if you look at MDN documentation on this it says that you take the last element and the first element and that would be o and k.

No, in the code here:

```
.reduce((o, k) =>
```

`o` is the accumulator. It's either:

- the first value in the array being iterated over (on the first iteration), if no initial value is provided (but an initial value is provided) or
- the value returned by the last iteration

`k` is the key being iterated over. Since an initial value is provided, on the first iteration, this is the string `'scoreInEl'`. On the second iteration, it's the string `'maxInEl'`. Etc.

Since you're returning `o` at the end of each callback, and that refers to the initial value, the `els` the accumulator is the same every time.

It might be clearer to remove the confusing comma operator.

```
Object.keys(els).reduce((o, k) => {
  o[k] = document.querySelector("#" + k);
  return o;
}, els);
```

Or, with generic iteration instead of `reduce` (since the accumulator is the same each time, there's no point in using `reduce`):

```
Object.keys(els).forEach((k) => {
  els[k] = document.querySelector("#" + k);
});
```

That's much, much easier to understand. Don't try to be "tricky" by using `reduce` when it's not appropriate.

Comment: Wasn't me being tricky, I tried getting improvements on my code in stack change and the person wasn't responding to my questions, I wanted to implement it, but just wanted to understand it first lol. Thank you so much for this.